# Give height to scrollview without size in dp

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

I have to design the layout in the way that no hard coded values in dp,so I'm trying to use weight to give height to views.I trying UI has look the same in both mobiles and tablets.

But,the scroll view does not allow layout_weight I have set height to the scrollview. I dont' want to do this.

> How can I set the height of the scrollview or the main enclosed
>   container layout in it using weight/without hard coding in dp?

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"//WANT TO AVOID HARD CODING
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/roomno_et"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="ROOM NO"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="FIRST NAME"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="LAST NAME"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Checkin"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `ScrollView` in a parent `LinearLayout` and Assign weight to it.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight = "1">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/roomno_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="ROOM NO"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="FIRST NAME"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="LAST NAME"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="Checkin"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: But your code still has  android:layout_height="120dp" for scrollview